# Unable to wrap text inside div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an HTML,which should look as follows:-

[image]

I am able able to make it but i have a very specific requirement to make it such that when the font size of the first div increases(ie "Gross margin amount'),the div should wrap the text inside it.
But when the font-size of the same increases i get output like follows

[image]

Here is my code

```
<div style="width:132.5px; height:140.5px;background-color:#759BA6;display:block;float:left;margin:3px">
  <div style="background-color:#759BA6;width:100%;height:50%;float:top;color: black;">
    <span style="font-style:bold;font-size:18.52px;line-height: -moz-block-height;text-align:center;word-wrap: break-word;width:100%;height:100%">Gross Margin Amount</span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#084C61;font-style:bold;font-size:18.52px;line-height: -moz-block-height;text-align:center;width:100%;height:50%;color: white;float:bottom">
    <span style="font-size:13.52px"></span>2,483<span style="font-size:13.52px"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6mr0qgg/) i have created for reference.

I don't know what should i do to make the first div to wrap text inside it.Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier for others to help you if you split the markup and css, and format it in a readable fashion.

Comment: @Jeroen you are absolutely right but i dont know much html or css,so i don't actually know what you are asking me to do,so can you please ignore formatting and help me out here!!

Comment: How about `<div style="background-color:#759BA6;width:auto;height:50%;float:top;color: black;overflow:auto;">` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit cannot have scrollbar here!!

Answer (score 0):

Make height of the div to 100 %:

```
<div style="width:132.5px; height:100%.5px;background-color:#759BA6;display:block;float:left;margin:3px"><div style="background-color:#759BA6;width:100%;height:100%;float:top;color: black;"><span style="font-style:bold;font-size:28.52px;line-height: -moz-block-height;text-align:center;word-wrap: break-word;width:100%;height:100%">Gross Margin Amount</span></div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6mr0qgg/2/)